# Unable to get ui:inputDate render well when injected from a Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-out

I am using the stock `<ui:inputDate displayDatePicker="true" />` element.
When it's displayed from a native lightning page everything works correctly.

[image]

The same component is injected in a Visualforce Page and everything looks and behaves the same apart from the inputDate element: css rules don't seem to be applied.

[image]

My `aura:application` is extending `ltng:outApp`. What am I missing?

Comment: I think my problems depends on the current limitations. I found this statement in the **Lightning Components Developer Guide**:

If you’re using standard components in your apps, they might not be fully styled, or behave as documented, when they’re used in Lightning Out or Lightning Components for Visualforce.

Answer (score 1):

your app might be extending ltng:outApp this will provide you all standard salesforce css i.e slds (salesforce lightning design system).

but if your app extends ltng:outAppUnstyled this will not give you standard salesforce css.

while slds is not available on visualforce page.

Comment: But I am extending **ltng:outApp**

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any good solution. But there is a hack you can use . Use following style in any vf page which is using ui:inputDate or ui:inputDateTime component

```
<style>
        .uiDayInMonthCell--default {
        width: 2rem;
        height: 2rem;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        min-width: 2rem;
        line-height: 2rem;
        border-radius: 50%;
        }
        a.uiDayInMonthCell--default {
        width: 2rem;
        height: 2rem;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        min-width: 2rem;
        line-height: 2rem;
        border-radius: 50%;
        font-size:small;
        }
        .uiDatePicker--default {
        margin-top: .25rem;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: .75rem;
        display: none;
        font-weight: 400;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16);
        border: 1px solid rgb(216, 221, 230);
        border-radius: .25rem;
        float: left;
        min-width: 240px;
        max-width: 400px;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        }
        *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .uiDatePicker--default .dateBar {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        padding: .25rem;
        background-color: white;
        height: 30px;
        }
        .uiDatePicker--default .datepicker__filter--month {
        width: 70%;
        margin-top: 13px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 0 .25rem 0 0;
        }
        .uiDatePicker--default .dateBar .prevLinks {
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: .75rem;
        margin-top: -10px;
        }
        .uiDatePicker--default a {
        text-decoration: none;
        }
        .assistiveText {
        position: absolute!important;
        height: 1px;
        width: 1px;
        overflow: hidden;
        clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
        }
        .uiDatePicker--default .dateBar .nextLinks {
        float: right;
        text-align: right;
        margin-right: .75rem;
        -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4;
        -webkit-order: 3;
        -ms-flex-order: 3;
        order: 3;
        margin-top: -10px;
        }
        .uiDatePicker--default .datepicker__filter--month .monthYear {
        line-height: 16px;
        font-size: .75rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin-top: 5px;
        font-weight: 100;
        }
        .uiDatePicker--default .datepicker__filter--year {
        width: 30%;
        }
        .uiDatePicker--default .picklist__label {
        font-size: .75rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        }
        .uiDatePicker--default .select {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        padding: 0 30px 0 14px;
        background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zd…w9IiM1NTY5OEQiIHdpZHRoPSIyNy42IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjIxIi8+DQogIDwvZz4NCjwvc3ZnPg0K);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 95% 50%;
        background-size: .8125rem .8125rem,100% 100%;
        }
        .uiDatePicker--default .select {
        font-family: 'Salesforce Sans',Arial,sans-serif;
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        color: rgb(22, 50, 92);
        border: 1px solid rgb(216, 221, 230);
        border-radius: .25rem;
        width: 100%;
        transition: border .1s linear,background-color .1s linear;
        height: 1.875rem;
        }
        button, select {
        text-transform: none;
        }
        button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
        color: inherit;
        font: inherit;
        margin: 0;
        }
        *, *:before, *:after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        user agent stylesheet
        select:not([size]):not([multiple]), select[size="0"], select[size="1"] {
        background-color: buttonface;
        }
        user agent stylesheet
        keygen, select, select[size="0"], select[size="1"] {
        border-radius: 0px;
        border-color: rgb(169, 169, 169);
        }
        user agent stylesheet
        select:not(:-internal-list-box) {
        overflow: visible !important;
        }
        user agent stylesheet
        select {
        -webkit-appearance: menulist;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        align-items: center;
        white-space: pre;
        -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        cursor: default;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: initial;
        border-image: initial;
        }
        user agent stylesheet
        keygen, select {
        border-radius: 5px;
        }
        user agent stylesheet
        input, textarea, keygen, select, button {
        text-rendering: auto;
        color: initial;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        word-spacing: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        text-indent: 0px;
        text-shadow: none;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: start;
        margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
        font: 13.3333px Arial;
        }
        user agent stylesheet
        input, textarea, keygen, select, button, meter, progress {
        -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
        }table {
        width: 100%;
        }
        table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        }
        *, *:before, *:after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        user agent stylesheet
        table {
        display: table;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 2px;
        border-color: grey;
        }
        Inherited from div#32:404;a.visible.DESKTOP.uiDatePicker--default.uiDatePicker
        .uiDatePicker--default {
        margin-top: .25rem;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: .75rem;
        display: none;
        font-weight: 400;
        }
        thead {
        display: table-header-group;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-color: inherit;
        }
        Inherited from table.calGrid
        table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        }
        user agent stylesheet
        table {
        display: table;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 2px;
        border-color: grey;
        }
        Inherited from div#32:404;a.visible.DESKTOP.uiDatePicker--default.uiDatePicker
        .uiDatePicker--default {
        margin-top: .25rem;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: .75rem;
        display: none;
        font-weight: 400;
        }
        tr {
        display: table-row;
        vertical-align: inherit;
        border-color: inherit;
        }
        Inherited from table.calGrid
        table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        }
        user agent stylesheet
        table {
        display: table;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 2px;
        border-color: grey;
        }
        Inherited from div#32:404;a.visible.DESKTOP.uiDatePicker--default.uiDatePicker
        .uiDatePicker--default {
        margin-top: .25rem;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: .75rem;
        display: none;
        font-weight: 400;
        }
        .uiDatePickerGrid--default th {
        padding: .5rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: rgb(84, 105, 141);
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: lowercase;
        }
        caption, th, td {
        text-align: left;
        }
        td, th {
        padding: 0;
        }
        *, *:before, *:after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        user agent stylesheet
        th {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: -internal-center;
        }
        user agent stylesheet
        td, th {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: inherit;
        }
        tbody {
        display: table-row-group;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-color: inherit;
        }
        tr {
        display: table-row;
        vertical-align: inherit;
        border-color: inherit;
        }
        .uiDatePickerGrid--default td {
        padding: .25rem;
        text-align: center;
        }
        caption, th, td {
        text-align: left;
        }
        td, th {
        padding: 0;
        }
        *, *:before, *:after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        user agent stylesheet
        td, th {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: inherit;
        }
        uiDayInMonthCell--default, .uiDayInMonthCell--default:link, .uiDayInMonthCell--default:visited, .uiDayInMonthCell--default:hover, .uiDayInMonthCell--default:active {
        color: rgb(84, 105, 141);
        }
        .uiDatePicker--default a {
        text-decoration: none;
        }
        .uiDayInMonthCell--default {
        width: 2rem;
        height: 2rem;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        min-width: 2rem;
        line-height: 2rem;
        border-radius: 50%;
        }
        a, button {
        cursor: pointer;
        }
        a {
        color: rgb(0, 112, 210);
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-transition: color .1s linear;
        transition: color .1s linear;
        }
        a {
        background-color: transparent;
        }
        user agent stylesheet
        a:-webkit-any-link {
        color: -webkit-link;
        text-decoration: underline;
        cursor: auto;
        }
        html {
        font-family: 'Salesforce Sans',Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
        line-height: 1.5;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        color: rgb(22, 50, 92);
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
        }
        body.desktop {
        overflow: visible;
        }
        body {
        font-size: .8125rem;
        background: transparent;
        }
        body {
        margin: 0;
        }
        .uiDatePicker--default .dateBar select {   
        font-size: 15px;
        color: rgb(22, 50, 92);
        background-color: white;
        }
        .uiDatePickerGrid--default thead {
        background-color: white;
        }
        .uiDatePickerGrid--default .calGrid th {
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }
        .uiDatePickerGrid--default .calGrid .calRow td {
            border: white;
        }
        a.uiDayInMonthCell--default.desktop:hover, a.uiDayInMonthCell--default.desktop:focus, a.uiDayInMonthCell--default.desktop:active {
            background-color: #e1e1e1;
            text-shadow: 0 0 0 white;
            outline: white;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 white; 
        }
        .uiDatePickerGrid--default thead {
            border-bottom: 0px 
        }
        .uiDatePicker--default .navLink:hover {
            background-color: white;
            border-color: white;
            outline: none;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px white;
        }

    </style>
```